# using node-inspector with meteor on windows

Tags: meteor, node-inspector

I am trying to use `node-inspector` to help debug my meteor app on windows. As indicated here: https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteordebug

running meteor debug should start the `node-inspector` portal at http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858 by default.

I can navigate to the url, but do not see any files under "Sources" (or anywhere for that matter)

I've tried setting the port manually, and tried installing node-inspector via npm as well in case it was needed, and tried running `"meteor NODE_OPTIONS='--debug'` ...but those don't seem to help (and the `NODE_OPTIONS` parameter doesn't even work...)

what am I missing/why don't the files show up? how can I debug this debuggng issue...?

PS - i do see `Notifications permission has been blocked as the user has dismissed the permission prompt several times. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6443143280984064 for more information.`
in the dev console on the debugger tab. Could this cause any issues? Not really sure what notification permissions I supposedly blocked.

**UPDATE:**
Also getting these 3 errors popping up in the console:

`Runtime.js:358 Assertion failed: Unknown experiment canvasInspection
Runtime._assert @ Runtime.js:358
21:53:06.599 Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'createSetting' of undefined
    at WebInspector.FilterBar.setName (:8080/ui/FilterBar.js:62)
    at WebInspector.NetworkPanel (:8080/network/NetworkPanel.js:47)
    at Function.WebInspector.NetworkPanel._instance (:8080/network/NetworkPanel.js:408)
    at eval (:8080/node/network/NetworkPanel.js:13)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)
    at <anonymous>
Runtime._reportError @ Runtime.js:367
21:53:06.772 Runtime.js:367 TypeError: Cannot read property 'sources' of undefined
    at WebInspector.SourcesOverrides._hideChromeSpecifics (:8080/node/sources/SourcesOverrides.js:12)
    at WebInspector.SourcesOverrides (:8080/node/sources/SourcesOverrides.js:5)
    at eval (:8080/node/sources/SourcesOverrides.js:63)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at evaluateScript (Runtime.js:153)
    at scriptSourceLoaded (Runtime.js:136)
    at <anonymous>`

many thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try http://localhost:5858 ?

Comment: yes, but that doesn't connect...just says "waiting for localhost" in the corner of chrome window

Comment: I also don't see instructions for using node-inspector being printed when I run `meteor debug --settings settings.json` ...but node-inspector is definitely installed